# character limitation on convert and search image files in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar

I realise this is a bit of edge case scenario but thought I would ask for help.
Our company has an old CSM database that I am trying to trim down and need to search through old incidents for useless image attachments on emails that I can then purge.
I have created an SP and Job that works for smaller images (facebook logo, twitter log etc.) but I'm struggling to get to grips with large files, particularly jpg file extensions.
The attachments are stored as datatype 'image' so I need to convert to varchar via varbinary to actual make a search that works, as below.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), column_name_1),2), *
from table_name with (nolock)
where ID = ''
```

which returns a searchable varchar that I can use in my SP.

```
SELECT ID FROM column_name_1 WITH (NOLOCK)
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), column_name_1),2) = 'some_Large_text_from_previous_select_convert'
```

The SP is not important, it's how to search for larger image files. Because of the double convert I can get out 16 772 characters but large image files are more than that, If I search using a LIKE then I get a string or binary would be truncated error. Has anybody come across this before and knows how to tweak my query please?

Comment: `NOLOCK` is not turbo button :)

Comment: Why are you searching binary (image) data for text?  What are you searching with/against?

Comment: Maybe whatever you're trying to do (which is not clear) would be better done in the CLR?

Comment: I can't use filenames or extensions, files get added as image001, image002 etc. and the location is named local\temp\similarly bad filename. So I need to find 1 image that I know is a email signature logo from a hand picked record. Then I use the above to convert it to something unique that I can then search other records for and delete them.

Comment: The more times I read this the less sense it makes. You can't convert an image to varchar and search for text? Are you expecting the image to have some sort of OCR string or something? As this stands your question is entirely unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: To clarify. I have been given an old CRM database that is huge and have been asked to trim. There are thousand incidents on it and most have dozens of attachments, mostly useless logos saved as datatype 'image'. I want to highlight images I know are useless and find where they exist and delete.
I needed to figure out a way to use the image and search, the first query works. I get a string that is unique for that image and can find it in any record. The issue is the size, an image file too large and the string is truncated, Is there is a way to increase the length of the result?